# How to find the reason for Bluetooth pairing failure in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to pair a device using Bluetooth. Sometimes pairing is working fine. but, sometimes `createBond()` function returns false. How to find the reason for the failure?

```
if(!device.createBond()){

     // want to find the reason for the failure

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This negative result can be caused when calling createBond() on an already bonded device. Remember that bonded does not mean connected, bonded means **paired**. Check if your device bluetooth settings already has a known configuration for the device you are trying to connect to. If so, deleting the Bluetooth configuration and then doing createBond will fix the problem.

Comment: Found the reason for the error in my scenario. I got this error when I tried to pair an already paired device.

Comment: Cheers mate! Hope it helped.

Comment: Anyway, I found it before you update the answer. Still I accepted it for other's future reference.

Comment: My devices are always BOND_BONDING. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for the error in my scenario. I got this error when I'm tried to pair an already paired device.

Now, I have added the check before it to check whether it is the paired device or not. It is working fine for me now.